# PHP isset for submit form with or operator

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit, isset

Is it possible to add the "OR" operator to php isset submit form code when there are two submit buttons with different names?
Eg:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submitRequest'] || $_POST['submit']))
```

The above code prompts and an error. Please advice.

Comment: Do you want a `TRUE` when both is set, both is not set or what else? The way you show the code is confusing.

Comment: i want one of the things to be true submitRequest or submit

Comment: please don't edit your question in such a way that the original question is lost. It is confusing for user who find this question later - the answers won't match the new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || isset($_POST['submit'])){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. You need each variable in its own isset functioYou cannot combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset()` on multiple variables:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // One of them was pushed
}
```

Be careful when passing multiple arguments to `isset()`. [As the manual documents](http://php.net/isset):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

So `isset($_POST['submitRequest'], $_POST['submit'])` would be the equivalent of `isset($_POST['submitRequest']) && isset($_POST['submit'])`. However, that second sentence can be useful if you want to check `!isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || !isset($_POST['submit'])`. Since when passed multiple arguments, `isset()` will return false for the first unset one, you can use `!isset($_POST['submitRequest'], $_POST['submit'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I had misunderstood the original post.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRequest'])||isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // you can do something here
}
```

**Original** (incorrect)

You can use this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submitRequest'], $_POST['submit'])){
    die("Fail");
}
```

If multiple parameters are supplied, the function will check all of them. This will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: It will echo fail if either of the variables are unset. It should echo fail if BOTH variables are unset.

Comment: I want it to be true if one of the parameters are set

Answer (score 0):

That's not how to use the or operator. You have to put it between two isset calls.

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || isset($_POST['submit']) ) { }
```

You always have to take a good look at the syntax. Remember that the or operator is used to make an entire condition evaluate to true if the left condition *or* the right condition is true. As such, you always need to use the or operator with two conditions.

Also, if you want to do this with the and operator, you can just use one isset call.

```
if ( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) { }
```

Comment: The second line of code only returns true if *both* are set. That would correspond to an `and` not an `or`.

Comment: Yes, read the comment I made above. That's exactly what I said.

Comment: @TinovanderLaan Apologies. For some reason I read 'or' instead of 'and'.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder no problem :) And Salman A, both were just examples of the logic to use. And no, the second one does in fact consider both. Look at php.net/isset for confirmation.

Comment: if (!isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || !isset($_POST['submit'])) i tried this and it does not work :/

Comment: @chamzor In comments you can (and should) wrap your code in backticks (`) so it will be highlighted.

Comment: @chamzor The answer that mgraph, many others, and myself have suggested works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the isset function on respective variables individually. You have an option of using either of the two syntax, depending on the convention you follow.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRequest']) || isset($_POST['submit'])){
   //do something
}

if(isset($_POST['submitRequest']) OR isset($_POST['submit'])){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to elaborate a bit:

`isset()`, `empty()` and a few other are **not functions, but language constructs**. As such, they don't work in all the ways one might expect according to them looking like functions.

The important part here is: **they only check variables**, they can't and don't evaluate the results of expressions.
The use of `||` makes `$_POST['submitRequest'] || $_POST['submit']` an expression. The result is only calculated temporarily, not stored in defined variable which can be set or empty.